# Vue.js unit testing ErrorBoundary

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-test-utils

I've built simple ErrorBoundary component for my project in Vue.js and I'm struggling to write unit test for it. Component's code below:

```
<template>
  <div class="overvue-error-boundary">
    <slot v-if="!error" />
    <div class="error-message" v-else>Something went horribly wrong here.</div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      error: false
    }
  },
  errorCaptured (error, vm, info) {
    this.error = true;
  }
}
</script>
```

I've created an ErrorThrowingComponent that throws an error on **created()** lifecycle hook so I can test ErrorBoundary:

```
const ErrorThrowingComponent = Vue.component('error-throwing-component', {
  created() {
    throw new Error(`Generic error`);
  },
  render (h) {
    return h('div', 'lorem ipsum')
  }
});

describe('when component in slot throws an error', () => {
  it('renders div.error-message', () => {
  // this is when error is when 'Generic error' is thrown by ErrorThrowingComponent
  const wrapper = shallowMount(OvervueErrorBoundary, {
    slots: {
      default: ErrorThrowingComponent
    }});
    // below code is not executed
    expect(wrapper.contains(ErrorThrowingComponent)).to.be.false;
    expect(wrapper.contains('div.error-message')).to.be.true;
  });
});
```

The problem is that ErrorThrowingComponent throws an error when I'm trying to actually mount it (thus failing entire test). Is there any way I can prevent this from happening?

EDIT: What I'm trying to achieve is to actually **mount** the ErrorThrowing component in a default slot of **ErrorBoundary** component to assert if **ErrorBoundary** will render error message and not the slot. This is way I created the ErrorThrowingComponent in the first place. But I cannot assert ErrorBoundary's behavior, because I get an error when trying to create a wraper.

Comment: what do you mean 'it throws an error when I mount it'? ...Theres an error being thrown on creation...(or am I missing something??)

Comment: I've clarified this in the EDIT section above.

Comment: is the `errorCaptured`  being invoked? can you try to add a log there and see if the issue reside in the capturer?

Comment: @Aviad, yes, the ErrorBoundary component has errorCaptured() hook that works. Component works as desired, I just cannot write unit test for it using vue-test-utils.

Comment: try refactoring your Errorboundry component to use a render function like this: https://github.com/dillonchanis/vue-error-boundary/blob/master/src/ErrorBoundary.vue

LMK if it changes something? this can point to a possible issue in how the mock interprets the render function vs rendering templates

Comment: @Aviad, no, unfortunately an error is still being thrown... Maybe there's an other way to test this? The ErrorBoundary component works after being refactored by the way.

Comment: This might be related to the core implementation of `vue-test-utils`. It appears that there might be a bug when `vue-test-utils` parses the templates. Maybe open a bug on their repo :)

Comment: @Aviad, thanks for help, I've checked with people from Vue Land and they provided me a different approach that solves my problem. You can find it in my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For anyone comming here with a similar problem: I've raised this on Vue Land's #vue-testing channel on Discord, and they suggested to move entire error-handling logic to a function which will be called from the errorCaptured() hook, and then just test this function. This approach seems sensible to me, so I decided to post it here.

Refactored **ErrorBoundary** component:

```
<template>
  <div class="error-boundary">
    <slot v-if="!error" />
    <div class="error-message" v-else>Something went horribly wrong here. Error: {{ error.message }}</div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      error: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    interceptError(error) {
      this.error = error;
    }
  },
  errorCaptured (error, vm, info) {
    this.interceptError(error);
  }
}
</script>
```

Unit test using vue-test-utils:

```
describe('when interceptError method is called', () => {
  it('renders div.error-message', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(OvervueErrorBoundary);
    wrapper.vm.interceptError(new Error('Generic error'));
    expect(wrapper.contains('div.error-message')).to.be.true;
  });
});
```